# How to open a local java class from sdcard in android

Tags: java, android, xml

Is it possible to open a java class from sdcard in android? or atleast set it as a contentview?

Comment: Why open java class instead put a text file write all the code which that java class should have and you can open a text file from sdcard. Any way your question is not clear enough? What exactly you want to do ?

Comment: I am creating a survey app, I was thinking that the questionnaire are in a form of a java class. so that I can call them like "setcontentview("file:"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Question/" +SurveyList.qUrl +"/index"+ pageNum +".class")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you do not need a java.class file. You can keep your data in a serialized format (XML, JSON, your custom way). For example lets have a String called `questionJson`:
**JSON**:

```
{ 
   "questionBody": "How much is 2+2?",
   "answers":["2","3","4","How should I know?"],
   "correctAnswerIndex": "2"
}
```

You'd have a class like:

```
class Question{
    public String questionBody;
    public String[] answers;
    public int correctAnswerIndex;
}
```

Using google's [Gson library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Question question= gson.fromJson(questionJson, Question.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You always need to export it as an .apk. You cannot run a java class file in android. You can then place the .apk file in a folder like downloads or so and then you can easily run it from the downloads app. Also you can export it automatically to your device by using the android sdk.

Hope this helps.